# Haskell: Reading from FS to "dynamically" create widgets in taffybar

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use taffybar as my status bar (uses Dyre framework so configuration is code). It has a widget that can show network interface statistics. In the default configuration this widget requires a `String` at compile time. I want it to create a widget per (non-loopback) interface dynamically instead.

This is what I have so far:

```
listNetworkDevices :: IO [String]
listNetworkDevices = fmap (map takeBaseName) $ getDirectoryContents "/sys/class/net/"

filterOutLoopback :: [String] -> [String]
filterOutLoopback = filter (\y -> not (elem y ["", ".", "lo"]))

netDevList :: IO [String]
netDevList = fmap filterOutLoopback listNetworkDevices

...

let nets = fmap (fmap (netMonitorNew 1)) netDevList
    ...
defaultTaffybar defaultTaffybarConfig {
    ...
    endWidgets = [ tray, clock, mem, cpu] ++ nets ++ [ bat ]
}
```

At this point I'm down to the following compiler error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[IO gtk-0.14.2:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.Widget]’
            with actual type ‘IO [IO gtk-0.14.2:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.Widget]’
```

Overall this the error makes sense since I'm making an `IO Widget` out of every `String`. So `IO [String]` turns into `IO [IO Widget]`.

What I don't understand is how to avoid doing this. Clearly I must have gone wrong at some point but I can't see where. I'm not even sure how to put the issue in words. I would be glad for any pointers!

Relevant material:

- endWidgets docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/taffybar-0.4.6/docs/System-Taffybar.html#v:endWidgets
- netMonitorNew docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/taffybar-0.4.6/docs/System-Taffybar-NetMonitor.html#v:netMonitorNew
- Source on github: https://github.com/travitch/taffybar/tree/master/src/System/Taffybar

Edit: complete listing:

```
import System.Taffybar
import System.Taffybar.Systray
import System.Taffybar.Pager
import System.Taffybar.TaffyPager
import System.Taffybar.SimpleClock
import System.Taffybar.Battery
import System.Taffybar.NetMonitor
import System.Taffybar.Weather
import System.Taffybar.Widgets.PollingBar
import System.Taffybar.Widgets.PollingGraph
import System.Information.Memory
import System.Information.CPU
import System.Directory ( getDirectoryContents )
import System.FilePath ( takeBaseName )
import Control.Monad

memCallback = do
  mi <- parseMeminfo
  return [memoryUsedRatio mi]

cpuCallback = do
  (userLoad, systemLoad, totalLoad) <- cpuLoad
  return [totalLoad, systemLoad]

listNetworkDevices :: IO [String]
listNetworkDevices = fmap (map takeBaseName) $ getDirectoryContents "/sys/class/net/"

filterOutLoopback :: [String] -> [String]
filterOutLoopback = filter (\y -> not (elem y ["", ".", "lo"]))

netDevList :: IO [String]
netDevList = fmap filterOutLoopback listNetworkDevices

myPagerConfig = defaultPagerConfig {}

main = do
  let memCfg = defaultGraphConfig { graphDataColors = [(1, 0, 0, 1)] }
      cpuCfg = defaultGraphConfig { graphDataColors = [ (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                                      , (1, 0, 1, 0.5)
                                                      ]
                                  }
      clock = textClockNew Nothing "<span fgcolor='orange'>%a %b %d %H:%M</span>" 1
      pager = taffyPagerNew myPagerConfig
      mem = pollingGraphNew memCfg 1 memCallback
      cpu = pollingGraphNew cpuCfg 1 cpuCallback
      bat = textBatteryNew "$percentage$% $time$" 1
      tray = systrayNew

      --nets = [ netMonitorNew 1 "wlp0s2" ]
      nets = fmap  (fmap (netMonitorNew 1)) netDevList

  defaultTaffybar defaultTaffybarConfig { startWidgets = [ pager ]
                                        , endWidgets = [ tray, clock, mem, cpu] ++ nets ++ [ bat ]
                                        }
```

Edit: Error message:

```
.config/taffybar/taffybar.hs:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[IO
                                     gtk-0.14.2:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.Widget]’
                with actual type ‘IO [IO gtk-0.14.2:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.Widget]’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘nets’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘nets ++ [bat]’
```

Comment: could you add the complete error message and a complete source code function that throws the error. Also I think your source code is incorrect - the `let`-statement does not make sense in a file.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: done.

Comment: I have not studied the code thoroughly but my guess would be either memcallback or cpucallback are wrong (add type signature) or `nets=` should be `nets <-`

Comment: Those parts do work. If you replace `nets = ` with the commented out version on the line above, everything compile and works fine (also, compare with https://github.com/travitch/taffybar/blob/master/taffybar.hs.example ). Except for the obvious issue that I only have a single hardcoded interface.
If I do `nets <-` ghc complains with a parse error that I'm not in a `do` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this as I usually do, since I don't have taffybar installed on this machine, but I suspect the following small change should help you make progress:

```
main = do
  let memCfg = defaultGraphConfig { graphDataColors = [(1, 0, 0, 1)] }
      cpuCfg = defaultGraphConfig { graphDataColors = [ (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                                      , (1, 0, 1, 0.5)
                                                      ]
                                  }
      clock = textClockNew Nothing "<span fgcolor='orange'>%a %b %d %H:%M</span>" 1
      pager = taffyPagerNew myPagerConfig
      mem = pollingGraphNew memCfg 1 memCallback
      cpu = pollingGraphNew cpuCfg 1 cpuCallback
      bat = textBatteryNew "$percentage$% $time$" 1
      tray = systrayNew

  -- this line is the only one that changed
  nets <- fmap  (fmap (netMonitorNew 1)) netDevList

  defaultTaffybar defaultTaffybarConfig { startWidgets = [ pager ]
                                        , endWidgets = [ tray, clock, mem, cpu] ++ nets ++ [ bat ]
                                        }
```

There may be other problems, but this should address the one described in the question.

There are plenty of stylistic changes that could/should be made as well, of course; for example, I think I would probably write the last two lines this way instead:

```
  nets <- netDevList
  defaultTaffybar ... { ..., endWidgets = ... ++ map netMonitorNew nets ++ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed solve the issue. Do you think you could comment in a sentence or two what exactly I was doing (wrong) originally? I'm still trying to develop the language to talk about Haskell code.

Comment: @McEnroe You might like sigfpe's [introduction to IO](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html).